# Relu-Layer-Output drops to all Zeros after 10 training steps

Tags: tensorflow

I am using the translate-example to train a seq2seq-task. This part works.

Then I am trying to use the hidden state at end of encoding to predict a price range of the product that the seq2seq-part works with.

As I am having an issue with the relu-Layer (see below) I am allowing backprop only on this part of the Graph.

Here is the code for that part:

```
# First Layer
W_price_first_layer = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_layers*size, self.prices_hidden_layer_size], stddev=0.35), name="W_price_first_layer")
B_price_first_layer = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([self.prices_hidden_layer_size]), name="B_price_first_layer")

# Uses Hidden State of seq2seq (translate.py) at end of encoding
self.output_price_first_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(self.hidden_state, W_price_first_layer), B_price_first_layer)
self.relu_price_first_layer = tf.nn.relu(self.output_price_first_layer)

# Second Layer
W_price = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.prices_hidden_layer_size, self.prices_bit_size], stddev=0.35), name="W_price")
W_price_t = tf.transpose(W_price)
B_price = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([self.prices_bit_size]), name="B_price")

# Prepare Backprop
self.output_price_second_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(self.relu_price_first_layer, W_price),B_price)
self.label_price      = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[self.batch_size], name="price_label")
self.loss_price       = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(self.output_price_second_layer, self.label_price)
self.optimizer_price  = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
var_list_prices       = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, "prices")
self.training_op_price = self.optimizer_price.minimize(self.loss_price, var_list=var_list_prices)
```

Now the problem: The Relu-Output of the first layer (self.relu_price_first_layer) drops to all zeros after about 10 or 20 training steps and never recovers. This happened faster when I didnt isolate the backprop of this part of the Graph. Problem now appears later, but still extremely fast (after 10 steps as said). Any ideas? Thx

Comment: I'd first try and isolate the problem more; it's hard for me to debug at first glance. Try switching ReLU with some other nonlinearity, such as the sigmoid, and see if you have the same behavior. ReLUs can suffer from the "dead neuron" problem. You can also try removing the biases. You might have an error upstream in your graph or the labels might not be in the proper format.

Comment: Thought it was a bug. But you were right: Sigmoid helped. What also helped: I frst allowed the basicseq2seq to learn and stabilize and only then switched learning on in the extra part. Thx